# Extracting an adjaceny matrix containing haversine distance from points on map

Tags: python, performance, beginner, coordinate-system

I am extracting 10 lat/long points from Google Maps and placing these into a text file. The program should be able to read in the text file, calculate the [haversine](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/) distance between each point, and store in an adjacency matrix. The adjacency matrix will eventually be fed to a 2-opt algorithm, which is outside the scope of the code I am about to present.

The following code is functional, but extremely inefficient. If I had 1000 points instead of 10, the adjacency matrix would need 1000 x 1000 iterations to be filled. Can this be optimized?

```
import csv
from haversine import haversine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def read_two_column_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True, )
        long = []
        lat = []
        for col in csv_input:
            x = float(col[0])  # converting to float
            y = float(col[1])
            long.append(x)
            lat.append(y)

    return long, lat


def display_points(long, lat):
    plt.figure()
    plt.ylabel('longitude')
    plt.xlabel('latitude')
    plt.title('longitude vs latitude')
    plt.scatter(long, lat)
    plt.show()


def main():
    long, lat = read_two_column_file('latlong.txt')

    points = []
    for i in range(len(lat)):
            coords = tuple([lat[i], long[i]])  # converting to tuple to be able to perform haverine calc. 
            points.append(coords)

    hav = []
    for i in range(len(lat)):
        for j in range(len(long)):
            hav.append(haversine(points[i], points[j]))

    np.asarray(hav)
    adj_matrix = np.reshape(hav, (10, 10))  # reshaping to 10 x 10 matrix
    print(adj_matrix)

    display_points(long, lat)


main()
```

Sample Input:

```
35.905333, 14.471970
35.896389, 14.477780
35.901281, 14.518173
35.860491, 14.572245
35.807607, 14.535320
35.832267, 14.455894
35.882414, 14.373217
35.983794, 14.336096
35.974463, 14.351006
35.930951, 14.401137
```

Sample Output:

```
[[ 0.          1.15959635  5.15603243 12.15003864 12.66090817  8.06760374
  11.25481465 17.31108648 15.37358741  8.34541481]
 [ 1.15959635  0.          4.52227294 11.19223786 11.50131214  7.32033758
  11.72388583 18.35259685 16.41378987  9.29953014]
 [ 5.15603243  4.52227294  0.          7.44480948 10.26177912 10.15688933
  16.24592213 22.1101544  20.18967731 13.40020548]
 [12.15003864 11.19223786  7.44480948  0.          7.01813758 13.28961044
  22.25645098 29.42422794 27.49154954 20.48281039]
 [12.66090817 11.50131214 10.26177912  7.01813758  0.          9.22215871
  19.74293886 29.16680205 27.25540014 19.97465594]
 [ 8.06760374  7.32033758 10.15688933 13.28961044  9.22215871  0.
  10.66219491 21.06632671 19.24994647 12.24773666]
 [11.25481465 11.72388583 16.24592213 22.25645098 19.74293886 10.66219491
   0.         11.67502344 10.21846781  6.08016463]
 [17.31108648 18.35259685 22.1101544  29.42422794 29.16680205 21.06632671
  11.67502344  0.          1.93885474  9.20353461]
 [15.37358741 16.41378987 20.18967731 27.49154954 27.25540014 19.24994647
  10.21846781  1.93885474  0.          7.28280909]
 [ 8.34541481  9.29953014 13.40020548 20.48281039 19.97465594 12.24773666
   6.08016463  9.20353461  7.28280909  0.        ]]
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review and congratulations on writing a decent question on your first try.

Comment: This is a great first question, I hope you get some good feedback.

Comment: If you want your code to be error prone, you actually want it so it is easy to have bugs. You maybe meant error proof?

Comment: Well spotted @Graipher! Seems like I want suggestions on how to actually include bugs in my code. Thanks for pointing out, will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than half of your code is being used to convert from one data format to another (from two lat and long list to tuples and then from a list of lists to an array).

The easiest to understand version would be to use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
def read_two_column_file(file_name):
    return np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=", ")
```

This is then a 2D `numpy.array`. However, [this is actually a lot slower than it could be](http://akuederle.com/stop-using-numpy-loadtxt), so you could also use `pandas.read_csv` instead:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_two_column_file(file_name):
    return pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None).values
```

Which one is faster depends on the size of your file.

Now we need to modify the `display_points` function to work with this new data format:

```
def display_points(points):
    plt.figure()
    plt.ylabel('longitude')
    plt.xlabel('latitude')
    plt.title('longitude vs latitude')
    plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
    plt.show()
```

Now for the actual calculation. First, you can use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) to get all pairs of points. Then you can insert them directly into the correct row of an array:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def main():

    points = read_two_column_file(file_name)

    adj_matrix = np.empty(len(points)**2)
    for i, (point1, point2) in enumerate(combinations_with_replacement(points, 2)):
        adj_matrix[i] = haversine(point1, point2)
    adj_matrix.reshape((len(points), len(points))

    print(adj_matrix)
    display_points(points)
```

This can probably be further improved by using [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to get the combinations of points and using [a vectorized version of the haversine function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/4042267).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback. Will get back after I look into all suggestions and try to implement.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error on Line 28 being: `adj_matrix[i] = haversine(point1, point2)`. `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` I haven't yet found what's wrong.

Comment: @Rrz0 That sounds odd. Will also investigate when I get home later.

Comment: I suspect tuple unpacking gone wrong, somewhere.

Comment: @Rrz0: I just tested it again, it works on my machine with Python 3.6.3. Did you maybe not replace the `read_two_column_file` function?

Comment: Thanks for testing . Strange, I thought I had replaced everything. I'll try once more and get back to you.

Comment: @SandeepAnand That limitation depends entirely how much (free) RAM your computer has.